# Composite pattern and Dependency Injection

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, composite

I see that Composite pattern and dependency injection means

```
public function __construct(ClassToUseInterface $class) {
$this->class = $class
}
```

So, what's the difference ?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia articles on the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Can you explain to us what you don't understand about these patterns and their relationship after reading those articles?

Comment: @Steven I believe the OP is confusing composition with dependency injection. Regardless of that, my answer attempts to clarify any doubts that the OP might have about the two design principles. Do let me know how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as presented in your question neither represents dependency-injection, nor does it represent the composite pattern. Your code represents what is known as [Dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Let's answer your question :

1. One way for your code to truly represent `Dependency injection` is to call the `construct` function from code that is external to the class in which the `construct` method is defined, passing it a concrete object that implements `ClassToUseInterface` . The external code is said to **inject** the dependency and this is therefore known as `Dependency injection`.
2. The composite pattern (not to be confused with composition) on the other hand is a relationship such that a class represents both, an `IS-A` and a `HAS-A` relationship at the same time with a `class` or `interface` that it extends from or implements. This allows a group of objects of a class to behave as if they represented a single object of the class.

Since I am not familiar with the `php` syntax, [here](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/the-missing-patterns-of-the-php-manual/#p6) is a good example of the `Composite pattern` in `php`. In this example, the `draw` method in the `Container` class operates upon a group of `Graphic` objects. To the caller, it's as if the `draw` function was called on a single `Graphic` object.

In case the linked example does not work, here is the code from the link (by Dario Ocles; 18 Jun 2007)

```
<?php
abstract class Graphic{
    abstract public function draw();
}

class Triangle extends Graphic{
    private $name = '';

    public function __construct($name = 'unknown'){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function draw(){
        echo '-I\'m a triangle '.$this->name.'.<br>';
    }
}

class Container extends Graphic{
    private $name = '';
    private $container = array();

    public function __construct($name = 'unknown'){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function draw(){
        echo 'I\'m a container '.$this->name.'.<br>';
        foreach($this->container as $graphic)
            $graphic->draw();
    }

    public function add(Graphic $graphic){
        $this->container[] = $graphic;
    }

    public function del(Graphic $graphic){
        unset($this->container[$graphic]);
    }
}

$tri1 = new Triangle('1');
$tri2 = new Triangle('2');
$tri3 = new Triangle('3');

$container1 = new Container('1');
$container2 = new Container('2');
$container3 = new Container('3');

$container1->add($tri1);
$container1->add($tri2);
$container2->add($tri3);

$container3->add($container1);
$container3->add($container2);

$container3->draw();
?>
```

In the linked/above example, the statement `$container3->add($container1);` passes a `Container` object to another object of `Container`. This will again be termed as `dependency injection`. The take away from this is that `dependency injection` and `composite pattern` don't mean the same thing. A `composite` object can be passed as a `dependency`. A `composite` object is not the same as `dependency injection`.

**Disclaimer** : All credit for the above program goes to it's original authors.